# How to aggregate expression in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report in ssrs 2008 r2 and last column is made of expression (adding two column and multiplying it with third one)

```
=FormatNumber((Sum(Fields!CostHours.Value) + Sum(Fields!OtherCosts.Value)) * Fields!ExchangeRate.Value, 2)


        Curr
       -------
        exp

        exp

        exp
       -----

Total:  ?
```

[image]

How can i get the total of values generated from expression?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking? Did you want to add a new column at the end of the table object? or you cannot add the formula into the text box?

Comment: sorry, i have updated my question. I need to know about formula.

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse click on the text box and select Add Total ..

[image]

Comment: Add total is grayed out.

Comment: Cannot sum on expression. You need custom code [Example of work around](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d4a3969a-f3fc-457b-8430-733d7b590ff6/use-reportitems-to-sum-all-textboxes-in-a-tablix?forum=sqlreportingservices)